# MySQL Select when case

Tags: mysql, sql, database, case

i have those tables and i want to check the same attribute at the same time:

```
Person
id---name
1----Paul
2----Tom  
3----Jim 

Age
id---wert------personId  
1----28--------1 
2----25--------1  
3----30--------3
```

i want to do something like this.

```
    select * from Person p, Age where personId = p.id and CASE WHEN 
name = 'Paul' THEN Age > 28 WHEN name = 'Tom' THEN Age <....
```

How it is possible? With a CASE THEN in the WHERE clause? Please don't think about the structure of the table but only about the principle.

Any Ideas?
Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is possible like so

```
 select 
       * 
  from 
    Person p, Age  
  where personId = p.id 
 and CASE 
          WHEN name = 'Paul' THEN Age > 28 
          WHEN name = 'Tom' THEN Age <....  
          WHEN expr then expr that evals to bool
       END
```

Comment: it is possible to use the case when in hibernate? i try it but i got an exception.

Comment: I believe it's possible if you indicate you are running a native sql query.
Can you post exception details here?

Answer (score 0):

CASE WHEN THEN I believe need to be part of an expression, not an expression themselves. It's common use case is in the select, however you can use it in the where.

In a select this would be:

```
select 
    case name
        when 'paul' then 28
        when 'jim' then 30
    end
from X
```

To use it within an where you would do this:

```
select * from X where age = case name when 'jim' then 28 else 30 end
```

Depending on what you are attempting to achieve, you may want to consider OR statements instead of case in your where clause.